# Take off '[' from Json string?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, json

I have a JSON return string from MongoDB

```
[{'api_calls_per_day': 0.29411764705882354, '_id': ObjectId('51948e5bc25f4b1d1c0d303a'), 'api_calls_total': 5, 'api_calls_with_key': 3, 'api_calls_without_key': 2}]
```

I want to take off small brackets '[' and ']' from above string and result need be like:

```
{'api_calls_per_day': 0.29411764705882354, '_id': ObjectId('51948e5bc25f4b1d1c0d303a'), 'api_calls_total': 5, 'api_calls_with_key': 3, 'api_calls_without_key': 2}
```

Any idea how to remove small brackets from that string? Thanks

Comment: Just parse it as an array and get the first element.

Comment: `value[1:-1]` will do it even without parsing.

Comment: @SLaks, I'm new to python, any example will be great appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Most likely the problem is in your python code, mind providing that? Perhaps if you're wanting a single document, and not an array of documents, you should use `find_one()` instead of `find()` to get the proper results! :)

Comment: this is not a string.  It's a list.  It contains one dictionary which corresponds to your document.

Comment: I"m not sure, how has rights to devote the question. At least should have mention some valid reason to do that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting a string? If you are, it's just:

```
myString = MongoDBreturned[1:-1]
```

This takes a substring from the { to the }.

If it's not a string, and it's actually a List, then simply take the first (and only element), which is the json object.

```
json = MongoDBreturned[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's Python, string is a list. How about this

```
a = "[string with brackets]"

a[1:-1] # string without brackets (or without first and last char)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using string methods:

```
>>> a = "[string with brackets]"
>>> a.strip('[]')
"string with brackets"
```